# Can I expedite a Schengen Visa appointment for consulates in the US?

Tags: visas, schengen, new-york-city, spain

I live in the USA and hope to travel to Spain in ~6 weeks.

My citizenship requires a Schengen visa for traveling to Spain.

Applying for the Schengen visa requires making an appointment and appearing in person at the Spanish consulate in New York.

The wait time for an appointment is currently 10 weeks.

Unless I can secure an earlier appointment, I cannot obtain my visa in time to travel.

I have contacted two visa expediting services; they were unable to assist.

Can anyone offer advice on how to obtain an earlier appointment?

Or any other advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Have you tried calling the consulate?

Comment: Hi @Karlson, yes I tried calling the consulate. The visa department at the consulate plays a pre-recorded message saying that, due to numbers of applications, they cannot answer questions by phone and they will not respond to messages left behind.

Comment: Could you change your trip so that you enter the Schengen zone through a different country, and spend some time there? So you go for one who's consulate are less busy at the moment?

Comment: @Gagravarr, yes, my current plan is to enter through a different Schengen country. I have checked two adjacent Schengen states and their wait times are also greater than 6 weeks, but I'll keep trying. Because this plan incurs ticket change and added travel costs of ~ $400 I am hoping to find an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I'll be traveling to Germany, Austria, Hungary and Czech Republic. My main destination is Austria. My family and I had planned a European vacation this summer. My family resides in Asia and they had the visa stamped.

I reached out via email to Austrian embassy in LA explaining them that if I do not get visa in time the entire family vacation would be spoiled. They were kind enough to accommodate me.

I know this is a pretty old question. Just sharing my experience for anyone else who is in a similar spot.

Comment: This could be a good answer if you provided more detail.  Did your itineraryinclude travel to Austria? What did you say in your message to the Austrian consulate?

Comment: @phoog I've updated my original answer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are Spanish consulates in quite a few American cities:

http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/spanish-consulates-usa.html

Maybe you could obtain an appointment on shorter notice in one of the other cities.  New Orleans?

I may as well ask if you're sure you need to obtain the Schengen visa beforehand.  I'm a US citizen and I've traveled to Spain many times (I'm here now) and I've never had to obtain the visa beforehand.  Then again, I'm sure you've already looked into that.

Comment: Consulates yes but not all of the are capable of issuing visas.

Comment: On top of this OP is not a US citizen as he had indicated in the question plus they don't have a consulate in New Orleans.

Comment: Perhaps not all are capable of issuing visas, but hopefully more than one has this capability, and hopefully an appointment can be obtained at one of those without waiting 10 weeks.  I offered my experience as a US citizen in case the OP thought all non-EU citizens were required to obtain a visa in advance.  According to the link I posted, there is a Spanish consulate in New Orleans.

Comment: @stackoverflowrocks, Thank you for your suggestion, but I assure you I need a Schengen visa to enter Spain. I have obtained many in the past. This time I was surprised by the 10-week wait for an appointment.

Comment: @stackoverflowrocks, regarding alternate Spanish consulates in the US: the consulates in different US cities handle applications only from people residing in a set list of nearby US states. They (typically) will not service people from out of their list -- but I will look into how firm this rule is. Thanks.

Comment: How did it go with this?